How do I know a set of input states and measurements configurations is tomography complete?
In this paper: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.93.080502, the authors use input
states $\{HH; VH;
DV; LH; LV; VV;HV;HA;HL; LL; LA; DA; DR; VA; VL;
DH\}$ and measurements $\{HH;HV;VH;VV;
HD;HL; VL; VD; DD; RL; RD; DR;DV;RV;DH;RH\}$ to do process tomography of a Controlled-NOT Gate, see ref[21] of the paper.  Here,
H = [1;0];
V = [0;1];
D = 1/sqrt(2)*(H+V);
R = 1/sqrt(2)*(H-i*V);
A = 1/sqrt(2)*(H-V);
L = 1/sqrt(2)*(H+i*V);

It is said that there are an infinite number of such bases, so there is
substantial flexibility in choosing tomographic input and
measurement settings. We know there are 36 pairwise combinations of $\{H,V,R,D,A,L\}$,
so how do I know the input states and measurements configurations chosen from this set (36 pairwise combinations) are tomography complete?
